# Insert SQL value 'NULL' does it works the same as the NULL IN SQL?

Tags: sql, null

I'm newbie to SQL. Recently I just done something by deleted a table. I would like to restore the by manually insert the statement.

```
'2021-05-25 11:58:41.000',  NULL,
```

or

```
 '2021-05-25 11:58:41.000', 'NULL',
```

Should I use NULL or 'NULL' ? What happen If I use 'NULL' value?

Thank you

Comment: `'NULL'` is a string literal containing some text. `NULL` is the null value. Go with `NULL`!

Comment: You couldn't store `'NULL'` in an integer or date column

Comment: A simple analogy to show the difference: Without quotes it means "I don't know your name", but with quotes it means "Your name is Mr. Null". That's the difference of storing a `NULL` value and a string that happens to have the `'NULL'` content.

Comment: In simply words `NULL`is the keywort for Null-Values, while `'NULL'`is a legal not null value.

Answer (score 1):

They are different.  When you enclose something in single quotes, it becomes a string -- this is true of all keywords in SQL, including `NULL`.

When you use just `NULL`, it is the SQL keyword, and it is compatible with all types.

So, these are quite different:

```
insert into t (col1, col2)
    values ('2021-05-25 11:58:41.000', NULL);
```

and:

```
insert into t (col1, col2)
    values ('2021-05-25 11:58:41.000', 'NULL');
```

`'NULL'` is a string and only compatible with a string type.  You should get a type-conversion error if the column is not a string.

The one caveat is if you are storing the values in a text file for loading into the database.  In such a file, strings may or may not be delimited with single quotes, depending on the structure of the file.

Comment: it might be worth adding that the second statement only works if `col2` is a `varchar` (or similar) column. But not with e.g. a `date` column